# Correct Grammar in : " Applications for employment by the WTO

Tags: word-choice

I just found this sentence on the [WTO, World Trade Organisation, Website.](https://erecruitment.wto.org/public/index-wto.asp?lng=en)

- **Applications for employment "by" the WTO are equally welcome from women and men.**

I am wondering about the use of "by" instead of "at"

Comment: Might not a person be employed **by** the WTO?

Comment: One applies to be employed by an employer. Once employed, one is then employed at their premises.

Comment: Ok . But it still sounds weird and i still would prefer "AT". Would that be wrong ?